# What is the best online therapeutic intervention, in psychological support in higher education?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, health-psychology

With the threat of COVID-19, many jobs became home office and in many universities the teaching had to be readjusted to the online universe. Advances have been achieved in terms of **digital transformation**. Including the traditional psychological (or mental health) support services, which began to perform **teletherapies**, for example. Other tools include the use of **apps**, **gamification**, psychotherapy (or counseling) through **social networks**, including conversations (exclusively) in text or telephone assistance (audiocalls).  Given this scenario, I would like to know about studies and evidence that indicate which of these modalities of therapeutic intervention has the best impact, for this specific target audience, university students.

Comment: Where have you seen psychotherapy conducted through social networks? This to me is highly unethical and would not be permitted by governing bodies. Online one-to-one sessions can be conducted ethically online but not through social networks

Comment: Online therapy, also known as e-therapy, e-counseling, teletherapy, or cyber-counseling, involves the provision of mental health services and support over the Internet. This can occur through e-mail, text messaging, video conferencing, online chat, messaging, or telephone on the Internet. This does not mean doing therapy over Facebook, openly. But rather, using private chat

Comment: We know that some studies have stated that Internet-based cognitive-behavioral therapy can be as effective as traditional face-to-face cognitive-behavioral therapy in treating anxiety disorders. However, each country's professional association or council has its own ethical bylaws about online therapy and what limits should be observed. This is indeed a current and controversial topic. But one that has been increasingly well accepted.